# Summing series with factorials and fractions

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that $f(r) = r!$ and $f(r+1) - f(r) = r \cdot r!$

But I have no idea how to apply that to fractions.

I have a question, show that $\dfrac{r-1}{r!} = \dfrac{1}{(r-1)!} - \dfrac{1}{r!}$ and I have no idea how to solve it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{r-1}{r!}=\frac{r}{r!}-\frac{1}{r!}=\frac{r}{r\times(r-1)!}-\frac{1}{r!}=\frac{1}{(r-1)!}-\frac{1}{r!}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You could start with the right hand side and think about common denominator ...